# JSLint ( JSHint ) only a certain line range

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

I've been googling and can't seem to find anything definitive. Is there anyway to only use JSLint or JSHint on just a specific line range from the command line.

Maybe something along the lines of `jslint -L200,240 some_js_file.js`

Comment: It's hard to do that, since lint checks things like function names and variables, which might be out of a line number range. Why not just lint the whole thing and ignore the other lines?

Comment: Are you saying you only want to view the output for certain lines? Because @AndrewKoroluk is right. If it only evaluates those lines, you'll likely show errors that wouldn't otherwise exist. Assuming that's what you want, and assuming the functionality doesn't exist, you should consider submitting a feature request for it.

Comment: @AndrewKoroluk That makes sense. I'd be happy even just checking a particular function. I'm working in a really big file and am just wanting to lint the code I've added to it, as there seem to be quite a few errors in the file it's kind of annoying sifting through. But figured I'd ask on here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like my comment on the OP is what he was looking for. JSHint can't really be run for a certain line number range, since it checks things like function signatures and variable names.

Ex:

```
1 : function main() {
2 :    var omg = 'OMG!;
3 :    function myFunc1() {
4 :        alert('SPACE!');
5 :    }
6 :    function myFunc2() {
7 :        myFunc1();
8 :        alert(omg);
9 :    }
10: }
```

If I tried putting just lines 6-9 into JSLint, it would tell me that there is no function  `myFunc2()`, and no variable called `omg`.

The best solution, IMO, is to use an IDE like [Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) which will inspect your code for you on-the-fly.

Another solution would be to make a script that lints your file and then deletes anything not relating to your specified line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

A simplistic approach is to just copy the exact lines you want to http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't even read the whole sentence. I will leave this here and accept my shame.

Comment: This might be the approach I'll have to take. Thanks for the help.